# script in bash not understood using terminal in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash, scripts

Can anyone tells me what does this script means found in a `.sh` file::

```
[ ! -n "$T_R" ] && echo "Message Appear" && exit 1;
```

Comment: General programming questions should go on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TheSchwa I kind of agree, but [it turns out](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11631/why-was-my-off-topic-flag-declined) shell scripting is on-topic. Even `perl`.

Comment: My apologies then. Good to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First `&&` means execute the command which follows only if the command which preceded reports success (exit code zero).

The `[` is a test command.  `[ -n "$T_R" ]` means return success if the shell variable `T_R` is not empty.  The `!` in  `[ ! -n "$T_R" ]` negates the test so that success if reported only if the variable `T_R` is undefined or empty.

If `T_R` is undefined or empty, then the string `Message Appear` will be echoed to standard out and, since echo will report success, then `exit 1` will execute, terminating the script with exit code of `1`.